# PHP script is not working because of "raw data"

Tags: php, html, compression

I have the following php code:

```
<?php
include "../config.php"; //includes the connection data
$query="SELECT userinvites.user_id, COUNT( * ) AS user_count, users.fname, users.lname,        users.image
FROM userinvites
INNER JOIN users ON userinvites.user_id = users.user_id
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10"; //basic query that gets the data for leaderboard 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo '<table width="285" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">' ;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //echo "-". $row['image']. " - ". $row['fname']. " - ". $row['lname']. " - ".      $row['user_count'];
    //echo "<br />";
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td height='40'> ". $row['image'].  "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['fname']. " ". $row['lname']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['user_count']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

when i place this code alone in a .php page it works fine. when I try to import this script in an other .php page i get a message that sth is wrong with the data compression. Any ideas of what is happening?

Comment: What gives you the message? The browser? The other PHP script? A screenshot (or at least the actual error message!) would help.

Comment: Your text indentation is crazy!

Comment: whenever i run it on its own works fine. when i try to import it to another script i get a browser error. firefox says"The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression."

Comment: safari says "cannot decode raw data". I tried also to import it to a normal html style .php page but still getting the same message.

Comment: @user1339630 is that a full image you are outputting?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's the raw image data, then this should work for the while loop (change `image/gif` to the appropriate type):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo '<tr>'
    .'<td height="40">'
      .'<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '">'
    .'</td>'
    .'<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['fname'] . ' ' . $row['lname']) . '</td>'
    .'<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['user_count']) . '</td>'
    .'</tr>';

}
```

Comment: @Baba That's why I said "change `image/gif` to the appropriate type"